# write a sql to sort between the siblings of a tree

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a t-sql. I have a original table as follow.
   Table:

```
ID     | ParentId |  Data    |Sortno|
-------|--------- |--------- |------|
1902   |  0       |      210 |1     |
1803   |  0       |      212 |2     |
1604   |  0       |      251 |3     |
1005   |  0       |      256 |4     |
1021   | 1902     |      160 |2     |  
1022   | 1902     |      150 |1     |
19221  | 1022     |      90  |1     |
17222  | 1022     |      80  |2     |
13992  | 1803     |      70  |2     |
13881  | 1803     |      60  |1     |
1522   | 1902     |      150 |3     |
```

And I want to sort it and get a result table as follow:

```
ID     | ParentId| Data  |Sortno|
-------|-------- |-------|------|
1902   |  0      |   210 |1     |
1022   |  1902   |   150 |1     |
19221  |  1022   |   90  |1     |
17222  |  1022   |   80  |2     |
1522   |  1902   |   150 |3     |
1021   |  1902   |   160 |2     |
1803   |  0      |   212 |2     |
13881  | 1803    |   60  |1     |
13992  | 1803    |   70  |2     |
1604   |  0      |   251 |3     |
1005   |  0      |   256 |4     |
```

how do I write this T-SQL statement order by sortno between  the siblings ?  thanks in advance!

Comment: The Sortno column stand for what ?

Comment: Is it pure coincidence that your sorted result is sorting in **alphabetic** (not numeric) order?

Comment: Convert the **ID** as `VARCHAR` and Sort.. i.e. `ORDER BY CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)`

Comment: sorry，I made a inappropriate example data for ID column before,so I changed the data of ID and ParentId which is unordered actually.

Answer (score 1):

May not be the proper way but still it will work. Converting the `ID` column to `Varchar` in `Order by` will work for you.

```
CREATE TABLE #sts
  (
     ID       INT,
     ParentId INT,
     Data     INT
  )

INSERT INTO #sts
VALUES      (12,0,210 ),
            (13,0,212 ),
            (14,0,251 ),
            (15,0,256 ),
            (121,12,160 ),
            (122,12,150 ),
            (1221,122,90 ),
            (1222,122,80 ),
            (132,13,70 ),
            (131,13,60 )

SELECT *
FROM   #sts
ORDER  BY Cast(id AS VARCHAR(30))
```

**Result**

```
ID      ParentId    Data
12      0           210
121     12          160
122     12          150
1221    122         90
1222    122         80
13      0           212
131     13          60
132     13          70
14      0           251
15      0           256
```

Comment: I have changed the data of ID，ID is unordered.could you please answer it again?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PARENTID ORDER BY ID) AS SORTNO FROM  #STS
ORDER  BY CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(30))